# Make 3 buttons appear when screen goes under 576 px, invisible in wider screens

Tags: html, responsive-design, bootstrap-5, responsive

I try to make these buttons appear, but it never worked !
I finally found a code which on which they are never visible, and should appear under 576 px :
But this is just the navbar icon which is visible...
[image: the navbar icon appears under 576 px in place of the 3 buttons]
I asked 2 AI and they aren't yet able to do !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarNav"
        aria-controls="navbarNav"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav d-block d-sm-none">
        
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

If someone can find the way with bootstrap ?

Comment: Have you looked at the `display` documentation? E.g. `.d-sm-inline`, `.d-sm-block` ,etc. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/

Comment: yes, it's there that i found " Visible only on xs => .d-block .d-sm-none ", but i will look at d-sm-inline :-)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the responsive approach of bootstrap, is not that hard

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/extend/approach/#responsive

I give you an example of how to display/hide different elements on different screens

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- visible on sm screens and higher -->
<ul class="navbar-nav d-block d-none d-sm-flex">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- visible on sm screen sonly -->
<ul class="navbar-nav d-block d-none d-sm-flex d-md-none">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- visible only under sm screens -->
<ul class="navbar-nav d-block d-md-none">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: En dessous de sm ça parait aussi difficile ! fonctionne pas...